# Gerar Boleto em Java

Tags: java, boleto, lib

Me travei aqui olhando algumas libs para geração de boleto bancário e parece que a maioria foi abandonada. Gostaria de saber se existe alguma atualizada, melhor ou fácil de customizar.

Libs analizadas:

**Bopepo** - http://jrimum.org/bopepo/

**stella-boleto** - https://github.com/caelum/caelum-stella

Dentre os dois, a documentação do **Bopepo** é mais completa, mas tem alguns bancos que não funcionam. O fórum tem mais de 1 ano que não tem postagem.

O **stella-boleto** tem apenas alguns bancos. E não vi exemplo ou documentação para implementar um novo.

**Minha dúvida é: existem outros projetos semelhantes de código aberto que estejam ativos?**

Comment: Incrível como algo tao importante esta sem suporte pela comunidade.

Comment: Procurem alguem para auxiliar na configuração em um projeto Gradlew e não encontrei !

Answer (score 5):

Dos que citou, aparentemente o [stella-boleto](https://github.com/caelum/caelum-stella) é o mais usado atualmente, até mesmo por outros utilitários do [caelum-stella](https://github.com/caelum/caelum-stella), como o [stella-bean-validation](https://github.com/caelum/caelum-stella/tree/master/stella-bean-validation). Olhando o repositório do [stella-boleto](https://github.com/caelum/caelum-stella) a última alteração é de 16 dias atrás, e do [bopepo](https://github.com/jrimum/bopepo), de 14 dias atrás.

Hoje utilizo o [stella-boleto](https://github.com/caelum/caelum-stella). Realmente ele tem bem menos bancos implementados que o [bopepo](https://github.com/jrimum/bopepo) (suporta 13 bancos a mais no momento). Nunca usei o [bopepo](https://github.com/jrimum/bopepo), então não consigo falar muito como é o projeto.

No [stella-boleto](https://github.com/caelum/caelum-stella), até então não precisei implementar para um novo banco, os atuais (BB, Bradesco, CEF, HSBC, Itaú, Santander e Safra) me atendem, mas não é muito dífícil implementar um novo.

Basicamente você deve extender da classe abstrata [`AbstractBanco`](https://github.com/caelum/caelum-stella/blob/master/stella-boleto/src/main/java/br/com/caelum/stella/boleto/bancos/AbstractBanco.java) e implementar a *interface* [Banco](https://github.com/caelum/caelum-stella/blob/master/stella-boleto/src/main/java/br/com/caelum/stella/boleto/Banco.java), fazendo o seguinte:

- implementar os métodos que não esteja implementados em `AbstractBanco`, com `geraCodigoDeBarrasPara` (é aqui que você deve considerar as carteiras se o banco tem mais de uma), `getNossoNumeroFormatado`, `getNumeroFormatadoComDigito`, etc.
- caso a geração do dígito verificador seja diferente do padrão, implementar a interface [`GeradorDeDigito`](https://github.com/caelum/caelum-stella/blob/master/stella-boleto/src/main/java/br/com/caelum/stella/boleto/bancos/gerador/GeradorDeDigito.java) ou extender [`GeradorDeDigitoPadrao`](https://github.com/caelum/caelum-stella/blob/master/stella-boleto/src/main/java/br/com/caelum/stella/boleto/bancos/gerador/GeradorDeDigitoPadrao.java) e sobrescrever `getGeradorDeDigito()`.

Outros pontos interessantes destes dois projetos são:

- ambos estão sob a Licença Apache V2, então você pode fazer um *fork* dos projetos e seguir seu próprio caminho;
- ambos estão no github, então você pode também fazer um *fork* e ajustar o que tem necessidade (como implementar o boleto que precisa) e fazer uma *pull request*. Atende ao seu requisito e colabora com a comunidade também.

O JBoleto, como bem observou o @VictorStafusa, está descontinuado há um bom tempo, há uns 5 anos fiz um teste com ele com uma equipe de desenvolvimento e bem, ele tinha um projeto meio bagunçado e código macarrônico =D

Outras soluções, caso não queira adotar estas, é integrar com algum terceiro, como [Cobre Grátis](http://cobregratis.com.br/), [Boleto Bancário](https://www.boletobancario.com/home/), etc.

Dito isso, eu iria (e vou) de [stella-boleto](https://github.com/caelum/caelum-stella) mesmo, pela simplicidade de uso e extensão (mesmo não tendo documentação específica do *framework*, você terá que ler código para aprender a estrutura, que aliás é bem simples). Talvez seja interessante você testar ambas e caso surjam dúvidas mais específicas, incluí-las por aqui.

Comment: Sobre a emissão de boleto, não é necessário nenhum pagamento de taxa, carteira de pagamento ou algo assim? essa libs como Bopepo e Stella-Caelum simplesmente geram o Boleto?

Comment: @RaphaelAndrade, isto, elas geram a partir de como você a configura (ou inputa dados), os custos podem existir em certos casos.

Answer (score 1):

**Tente o jBoleto**

Já trabalhei com jBoleto e foi simples de usar, accredito que possa ser m bom candidato para seu requerimento. No caso, acho que o mais ativo é o Stella mesmo, ou seja com maior comunidade e "buzz"

https://code.google.com/p/jboleto/

Comment: Já trabalhei com ele em outubro de 2008 e era horrível. Cheio de bugs e de gambiarras. Gerava boletos com números errados. Olhando o link que você postou não há nenhum código, nenhum commit e nenhum download. O site oficial está inoperante e quase não há referências a ele depois de 2009. É difícil encontrá-lo hoje em dia, pois ele não existe mais nos locais aonde deveria estar hospedado oficialmente. Entretanto o encontrei nesse link, mas só os binários sem o código-fonte: https://code.google.com/p/projetofinal2009/source/browse/trunk/buyfast/buyFastNegocio/lib/jBoleto-1.0.jar

Comment: Por sinal, achei uma versão com os fontes. Novamente, nada muito confiável. Última atualização de 2009. Definitivamente não é um projeto ativo. https://code.google.com/p/xmlboletojava2/source/browse/#svn%2FDeskBoleto%2Fsrc%2Forg%2Fjboleto%253Fstate%253Dclosed

Comment: Vou tentar com o stella e ver o que acontece, no pior dos casos como mencionado acima vou tentar com o Cobre Grátis, Boleto Bancário.